# List devices eligible to use with pmount

Tags: linux, usb, debian, dvd, compact-disc

With `pmount` one can mount cds, dvds usb partitions (and what not) as a user. I wrote a program (in C) that wants to copy music (and stuff) from a removable device. I want to list these devices and present them to my user. Then I will mount the selected device with `pmount`, copy the stuff I want and then unmount it with `pmount`.

But I have no idea about how to list devices that are eligible for such task at a given moment.

I would prefer a `pmount` based solution if there is any. If there is no such option I would be satisfied with a good enough approximation using other (simlpe user runnable) tools.

I have Debian 7 on i686.

Answer (score 0):

First approximation:

AFAIK `pmount` is just a setuid-wrapper for `mount`. I'm not sure if there are additional restrictions.

There are various udev-aliases for all block devices in `/dev/disk/`, e.g. `/dev/disk/by-id/`. There are also utility programs like `lsblk` (maybe `lsblk -a -l` etc.), or `lsscsi`. Pick the one that comes closest to what you want.

Those include the already mounted devices, though, so you have to remove them with a script.